# Error when feeding new dataframe to predict with mlogit

Tags: r, dataframe, predict

I'm trying to recreate the example from this tutorial but there seems to be something wrong with how I feed the dataframe called by into the predict function?

This is from the tutorial https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2023/08/12/conjoint-multilevel-multinomial-guide/

```
preds_chocolate_mlogit %>% 
  group_by(dark) %>% 
  summarize(avg_pred = mean(estimate))
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##   dark  avg_pred
##   <fct>    <dbl>
## 1 Milk    0.0500
## 2 Dark    0.200
```

The average market share for milk chocolate candies, holding all other features constant, is 5% (

); the average market share for dark chocolate candies is 20% (

). These values are the averages of the predictions from the four groups where dark is either Milk or Dark.

Instead of calculating these averages manually (which would also force us to calculate standard errors and p-values manually, which, ugh), we can calculate these aggregate group means with predictions(). To do this, we can feed a little data frame to predictions() with the by argument. The data frame needs to contain columns for the features we want to collapse, and a by column with the labels we want to include in the output. For example, if we want to collapse the eight possible choices into those with milk chocolate and those with dark chocolate, we could create a by data frame like this:

```
by <- data.frame(dark = c("Milk", "Dark"), by = c("Milk", "Dark"))
by
##   dark   by
## 1 Milk Milk
## 2 Dark Dark
```

If we use that by data frame in predictions(), we get the same 5% and 20% from before, but now with all of {marginaleffects}’s extra features like standard errors and confidence intervals:

```
predictions(
  model_chocolate_mlogit,
  by = by
)
## 
##  Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)  2.5 % 97.5 %   By
##      0.20     0.0316 6.32   <0.001  0.138  0.262 Dark
##      0.05     0.0316 1.58    0.114 -0.012  0.112 Milk
##
```

this is the error I get trying to recreate the example ...

```
model_chocolate_mlogit

Call:
mlogit(formula = choice ~ dark + soft + nuts | 0 | 0, data = chocolate_idx,     method = "nr")



  Coefficients:
    darkDark  softSoft  nutsNuts  
      1.3863   -2.1972    0.8473  

> by <- data.frame(dark = c("Milk", "Dark"), by = c("Milk", "Dark"))
> library(mlogit)
> 
> # Creating 'by' data frame with levels of the 'dark' variable
> #by <- datagrid(dark = c("Milk", "Dark"))
> 
> # Using 'by' in predictions
> preds_chocolate_mlogit <- predictions(
+   model_chocolate_mlogit,
+   by = by
+ )
Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to supply a different dataset to the `newdata` argument. This error was
  also raised:
  
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: . ~   . |  . |  . |  
   ^
  
  Bug Tracker: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues
```

Comment: Why `| 0 | 0` in the formula?

Comment: placeholder for individual-level characteristics or alternative-level characteristics